# How to get foreign key of OneToMany relationship in JSP

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, one-to-many

I have two object that have OneToMany relationship, The foreign key is `userName`. When I check database, I can see the foreign key in there. But I have no idea why I receive nothing.

JSP

```
//ERROR HERE, I CAN'T GET DATA OF THE FOREIGN KEY 'USERNAME'
<div class="row">
    <label class="col-sm-2">Owner</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">${book.myUserAccount.userName}</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <label class="col-sm-2">Book's Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">${book.tensach}</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <label class="col-sm-2">Author</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">${book.tacgia}</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <label class="col-sm-2">Review</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">${book.nhanxet}</div>
</div>
```

Model MyUserAccount

```
public class MyUserAccount implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static final String ROLE_USER = "ROLE_USER";
private String id;
private String email;
private String userName;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String password;
private String role;
private String enabled;
private List<Book> book = new ArrayList<Book>(0);
private List<BookTrade> bookTrade = new ArrayList<BookTrade>(0);

public MyUserAccount() {

}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "myUserAccount")
public List<Book> getBook() {
    return book;
}

public void setBook(List<Book> book) {
    this.book = book;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "myUserAccount")
public List<BookTrade> getBookTrade() {
    return bookTrade;
}

public void setBookTrade(List<BookTrade> bookTrade) {
    this.bookTrade = bookTrade;
}

public MyUserAccount(String id, String email, String userName, String firstName, //
        String lastName, String password, String role, String enabled) {
    this.id = id;
    this.email = email;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.password = password;
    this.role = role;
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
```

Model Book

```
public class Book implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Integer book_ID;
private String tensach;
private String tacgia;
private String nhanxet;
private String tinhtrang;
private String theloai;
private byte[] image;
private String image_name;
private String data;
private MyUserAccount myUserAccount;

public Book() {

}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_NAME", nullable = false)
public MyUserAccount getMyUserAccount() {
    return this.myUserAccount;
}

public void setMyUserAccount(MyUserAccount myUserAccount) {
    this.myUserAccount = myUserAccount;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "book_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getBook_ID() {
    return book_ID;
}
```

How I mapped two object:

Controller

```
public String saveBook(@ModelAttribute("bookForm") @Validated Book book, BindingResult result, Model model,
        @RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile[] image, @RequestParam String userName, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
        throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

    MyUserAccount myUserAccount = myUserAccountDAO.findByUserName(userName);
    book.setMyUserAccount(myUserAccount);

    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("css", "success");
    if (book.getBook_ID() == null) {
        System.out.println(book.getBook_ID());
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("msg", "book added successfully!");
    } else {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("msg", "book updated successfully!");
    }

    for (CommonsMultipartFile aFile : image) {
        System.out.println("Saving file: " + aFile.getOriginalFilename());
        book.setImage_name(aFile.getOriginalFilename());
        book.setImage(aFile.getBytes());
        System.out.println("Damn that Shit!");
    }
    bookService.saveOrUpdate(book);
    // POST/REDIRECT/GET
    return "redirect:/motsach/" + book.getBook_ID();
}
```

DAO

```
public void save(Book book) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO Books(TENSACH, TACGIA, NHANXET, TINHTRANG, THELOAI, IMAGE, IMAGE_NAME, USER_NAME) "
            + "VALUES ( :tensach, :tacgia, :nhanxet, :tinhtrang, :theloai, :image, :image_name, :user_name)";

    namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(sql, getSqlParameterByModel(book), keyHolder);
    book.setBook_ID(keyHolder.getKey().intValue());
}

private SqlParameterSource getSqlParameterByModel(Book book) {
    MapSqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    paramSource.addValue("book_id", book.getBook_ID());
    paramSource.addValue("tensach", book.getTensach());
    paramSource.addValue("tacgia", book.getTacgia());
    paramSource.addValue("nhanxet", book.getNhanxet());
    paramSource.addValue("tinhtrang", book.getTinhtrang());
    paramSource.addValue("image", book.getImage());
    paramSource.addValue("image_name", book.getImage_name());
    paramSource.addValue("theloai", book.getTheloai());
    paramSource.addValue("user_name", book.getMyUserAccount().getUserName());
    return paramSource;
}
```

Comment: Add the code where you returning the Book object to jsp. Also did you verify it’s having the value within the controller before you return to the jsp?

Comment: Yes I did verify it, I can print that userName property in Controller but I can't get it in JSP

Comment: So you can see other values in jsp right? What is your web.xml version, is it 2.3. Or higher than that. Also try `<jstl:out value="${book.myUserAccount.userName}"/>` is this working or not

Comment: Yes, all other values can be display in JSP, except foreign key. I tried your code but there's no difference. My version is 3.0

Comment: In jsp header add the `<script type="text/javascript">var book = "${book}"; console.log(book)</script> ` so this will verify you are getting the all data to jsp and the structure. Make sure you have the necessary js libraries.

Comment: Thank you, but still the same

Comment: That will not fix your problem it will verify you are getting the all data to jsp. So are you able to see the myUserAccount child object with userName in browser console with above approach.